# Records wont add in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Using below code, i am not getting any errors. But the records i entered wont save to database php myadmin. Database wont update.
[image]

Comment: You're better off pasting your code here instead of an image...

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Also: It doesn't appear as `$query` is being set anywhere at all. You should be checking the return value of `mysqli_query()`, and then if it's false, echoing out the error associated with it (`mysqli_error()`).

Comment: If you really want someone to help you. It's better to copy and paste your code here instead of an image, else nobody gonna help you

Comment: Cut line number 5and paste it online 2 2.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. Don’t waste your time learning to make queries without using prepared statements. You’ll have to break the habit, so don’t learn it wrong in the first place
2. Your `$col` array in the object is constructed strangely. I doubt that’s what you want
3. When you implode `$col`, you’re not using the variable in the object. Wrong scope. When debugging, you should verify what the query is by printing it out before executing it. That would catch this error
4. Always pass variables to your methods instead of using globals. This helps prevent learning bad habits
5. Kudos for using an object. Make sure that each method only does one thing, and accurately returns success or failure